# Match keys with sibling object JSONATA

Tags: jsonata

I have an JSON object with the structure below. When looping over `key_two` I want to create a new object that I will return. The returned object should contain a `title` with the value from `key_one`'s name where the id of `key_one` matches the current looped over node from `key_two`.

Both objects contain other keys that also will be included but the first step I can't figure out is how to grab data from a sibling object while looping and match it to the current value.

```
{
  "key_one": [
    {
      "name": "some_cool_title",
      "id": "value_one",
      ...
    }
  ],
  "key_two": [
    {
      "node": "value_one",
      ...
    }
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of a 'join' operation (in SQL terms). JSONata supports this in a path expression.  See https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#-context-variable-binding

So in your example, you could write:

```
key_one@$k1.key_two[node = $k1.id].{
    "title": $k1.name
}
```

You can then add extra fields into the resulting object by referencing items from either of the original objects.  E.g.:

```
key_one@$k1.key_two[node = $k1.id].{
    "title": $k1.name,
    "other_one": $k1.other_data,
    "other_two": other_data
}
```

See https://try.jsonata.org/--2aRZvSL

Comment: This option seems to be working very well

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution for this.

```
[key_two].$filter($$.key_one, function($v, $k){
    $v.id = node
}).{"title": name ? name : id}
```

Gives:

```
[
  {
    "title": "value_one"
  },
  {
    "title": "value_two"
  },
  {
    "title": "value_three"
  }
]
```

Leaving this here if someone have a similar issue in the future.